# Determine if the following is a homomorphism and/or a isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Let **F** be the additive group of all continuous functions mapping $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathbb{R}$ be the additive group of real numbers. Define $\phi:$ **F** $\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $$\phi(f)= \int_{0}^{4} f(x) dx$$

I have not worked with an integral before to determine a homomorphism. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you know what is a homomorphism and what is an integral then it should be straightforward to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

It just follows by the fact that the integral is additive:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi(f+g)&:=\int_{0}^{4}(f+g)(x)dx\\
&:=\int_{0}^{4}(f(x)+g(x))dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{4}f(x)dx+\int_{0}^{4}g(x)dx\qquad\text{by the additivity of the integral}\\
&:=\phi(f)+\phi(g).
\end{aligned}
$$

Although $\phi$ is surjective, it is not injective, and hence, is not an isomorphism.

Comment: how would i go about proving or disproving surjectivity and injectivity for an integral?

Comment: Given any real number $c$, let $f$ be the constant function $c/4$. Then, $\phi(f)=c$, so $\phi$ is surjective. To see that $\phi$ is not injective, you need to find a function $f$, which is not identically $0$,  such that $\int_{0}^{4}f(x)dx=\phi(f)=0$.

Comment: im not seeing this....would you be able to provide a further explanation?

Answer (score 0):

To prove that $f$ is not injective, notice that $$\int_0^4 (2x-4)dx=(0-2)^2-(4-2)^2=0$$ and $$\int_0^4 0dx=0,$$ but $g \not\equiv 0$, where $g(x):=2x-4$.